# Chart.js Polar Area Chart is not scale right

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I found a problem when I was using Chart.js to create a Polar Area Chart. Here is the problem:
[Chart canvas is not displaying right in mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo7Ux.png)

And here is the code js code

```
var config = {
type: 'polarArea',
data: {
  labels: [
    "HTML/CSS",
    "jQuery",
    "PHP/MYSQL",
    "PS/AI",
    "PR/AE",
    "Processing",
    "Arduino"
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [95, 80, 30, 70, 60, 50, 50],
    backgroundColor: [
      "rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.7)",
      "rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.5)",
      "rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.5)",
      "rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.5)",
      "rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.5)",
      "rgba(13, 71, 161, 0.5)",
      "rgba(12, 161, 166, 0.5)",
    ],
  }],
},
options: {
  scale: {
    reverse: false,
    ticks: {
      min: 20,
      max: 90
    }
  }
}
};
window.onload = function() {
window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas"), config);
};
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?
Thanks so much!

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle here for attempt. Thanks so much!
https://jsfiddle.net/ksr9ucvb/1/

Answer (score 2):

in options try adding `maintainAspectRatio: false,` so that it does not try and keep a nice square which pushes the actual chart to a small size due to the large amount of labels.

```
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scale: {
      reverse: false,
      ticks: {
        min: 20,
        max: 90
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your comment first
however i have tried and it doesn't work :(

Comment: are you able to create a fiddle then which reproduces the issue?

Comment: cheers, it's odd i can not seem to find any settings that would allow for the control of this. also found that if you play with the size you eventually break the graph http://i.giphy.com/JjoQRjqKOj4Oc.gif

Comment: yea i found this problem also when set the maintainAspectRatio to false
make it true will work fine however the it will getting very small when the screen width is small too

Comment: so the only way i can get the graph to display at a nice size is to set the legend display to false, but that's not great as it means you loose your legend. i think this is worth adding as an issue on their github

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  In the end I have just set the legend to false and inserted a responsive image of the legend.  Not ideal at all but looks good on mobile.